# Why Tensorflow Language Model Example use different config for validation and testing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

In Tensorflow LM example, the author uses different config for validation and test:

```
valid_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mvalid, valid_data, tf.no_op())
test_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mtest, test_data, tf.no_op())
```

My question is that why we use different `num_steps` setting here? And does it contribute differently to the perplexity computation(e.g. both set `num_steps` equals 1)?

Comment: `num_steps=1` and `batch_size=1` are there to ensure that we don't bleed over state from one sentence to another, which would be cheating.

Comment: So, only this meaning?

Comment: AFAIK, this is the primary goal, to get clean scores.